# fail httpd restart: NameVirtualHost error

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf, centos6

I am getting this error [httpd restart fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJYPG.png)

```
[root@centos6 etc]# service https restart
Stopping httpd:   [  OK  ]
Starting https: httpd: apr_socketaddr_info_get() failed for centos6
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
[Thu Feb 18 22:38:09 2021] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
                  [  OK  ]
```

this is my httpd.conf: [NameVirtualHost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hivvK.png)
[Virtual Host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfaYP.png)

this is my /etc/hosts [/etc/hosts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVqFz.png)

knowing that I already created the directories and their index.html files [/var/www/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7HaA.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). On top, this is not programming related, thus off topic on stackoverflow - see [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0):

You assigned the same ip address to 2 different virtual hosts. Make one 192.168.0.**100** and the other 192.168.0.**101**.